# "localgauss" package in R- problem with plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate the codes at page 8 from the R tutorial ('localgauss', https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v056i12), in order to obtain the Figures of page 9. I run the following code:

```
install.packages("localgauss")

library("localgauss")
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- 0.6 * x + sqrt(1 - 0.6^2) * rnorm(1000)
xy.mat <- rbind(c(-1, 1), c(0, 0), c(1, 1))
lg.out2 <- localgauss(x = x, y = y, b1 = 1, b2 = 1, gsize = 15, hthresh = 0.01)

plot(lg.out2, plot.text = FALSE, plot.points = TRUE)
```

However, instead of Figure(s) on page 9, I get the following Figure, which is just a scatterplot without colors:

[image]

In the past this code has been running without a problem.

My first thought was that something is wrong with the `gglpot2` function, and I have tried to install an older version of the package with the use of the remote function:
remotes::install_version("ggplot2", "2.2.1")
but unfortunately still the problem remains.

btw I am using the R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)

Answer (score 0):

The plotting routine was removed from the library years ago. This may help:

```
library("localgauss")
x=rnorm(n=1000)
y=x^2 + rnorm(n=1000)
lgobj = localgauss(x,y)    

df<-data.frame(
  x=lgobj$xy.mat[,1],
  y=lgobj$xy.mat[,2],
  z=lgobj$par.est[,'rho']
)

cols <- rev(rainbow(7)[-7])
ggplot(df , aes(x = df$x, y = df$y, fill=df$z)) +
  geom_raster(interpolate=F) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = cols)
```